# Display resolution is wrong and the displays settings page doesn't offer the right resolution options

Tags: display, resolution, odin

My displays seems to be rendering at 1080p (settings page confirms this), but my display is 4k, but that isn't an option in the displays settings, page the highest it goes is 1080p for some reason. I found a similar questions suggestions to install mesa-utils, did that and restarted but the right options still aren't there. See attached screenshot. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: Added `sudo lshw -c video` output below:

```
emily@EmilysElementaryOSLinuxBox:~$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:27 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

[image]

Comment: This can sometimes be an issue with the video card not using the correct driver. Cold you [edit] your question to include the Terminal output of `sudo lshw -c video`? Have you also tried changing the Scaling Factor from LoDPI to HiDPI to see if the higher resolutions are available? 

Comment: @matigo Added :)

Comment: Is it a laptop or an external monitor? If external, maybe check if the cable is capable of that.

Comment: It's an external display and a dedicated mini PC, hadn't thought to check cable... let me check. I know with my windows PC on same monitor it shows 4k/60 with a standard/cheap HDMI cable. I will say the mini PC has a display port only so I have a display port to hdmi adapter inline, maybe that's causing issues. Let me tinker with cables a bit and see what I can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happy to report that getting a dedicated display port to display port cable and hooking directly up from the mini PC to the monitor resolved this issue and it was immediately recognized as 4K. So seems something with that display port to HDMI adapter wasn't allowing the OS or display driver or something to recognized the true resolution.

So TLDR = yeah just avoid display connection adapters and hopefully you won't also have this issue. :)